# How to preserve newline between textarea and database?

Tags: php, mysql, str-replace, nl2br

I am storing the user input in a text area into a database by using `nl2br().<br/>`
Now the problem is that I do not want to show the `"br"` tags when I show this input in a text area later but as a new line.`<br/>`
I was using `str_replace` but this seems to add a new line each time I get back and forth.
eg. user enters

```
Hello
World
```

It gets stored as

```
Hello<br />World
```

fine with me.
but when I display it again in the text area I get (after str_replace..ing the br tags with "\n")

```
Hello

World  //which if i submit gives me Hello<br /><br />World
```

Is there any way to achieve what I want to do over here?

Comment: Would would you use `nl2br` before storing it in the db. Don't do that.

Comment: Why to use nl2br function on text before storing it ? No need to use any function just save it as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Don't* store it with `nl2br`.  You should only store the *raw* data that is posted.  If you want to update it for display, use `nl2br` at that time.

```
if ($storing) {
    $dbstmt->execute($_POST['textarea-value']);
}
else {
    $textareaValue = $db->query($select);
    echo "<div>" . nl2br(htmlspecialchars($textareaValue)) . "</div>";
    echo "<textarea>" . htmlspecialchars($textareaValue) . "</textarea>";
}
```

Comment: Of course, i see it now, i was getting pretty crazy when i really didn't need to do anything. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The `nl2br` function appends a `<br/>` after each line break characters (`\r\n, \n\r, \n and \r`).

It does not however, remove the break line itself.  As a result, when you use `str_replace` to add the break line again, it is showing as double.

There are two options, firstly, change the `str_replace` to simply remove the `<br/>` without adding a new line character, or secondly to not use `nl2br`.

I would opt for the second, and use `nl2br` when I need to display the data inside html.